# Post entrie map to Firestore with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm attempting to post an entire map to Firestore using Flutter as follows:

```
Profile {
  String studentFirstName;
  String studentSurname;
  String yearLevel;
  String preferredHand;
  Map<String, dynamic> background = {};

  Profile({
  this.studentFirstName,
  this.studentSurname,
  this.yearLevel,
  this.preferredHand,
  this.background,
  )}

  Future<bool> createStudent(String schoolId) async {
  var newStudent = await db
    .collection('schoolStudents')
    .doc(schoolId)
    .collection('students')
    .add({
  'studentFirstName': _profile.studentFirstName,
  'studentSurname': _profile.studentSurname,
  'yearLevel': _profile.yearLevel,
  'preferredHand': _profile.preferredHand,
  'background': {_profile.background},
  }
}
```

However this fails with the below error message.

> Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of '_CompactLinkedHashSet<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Can someone let me know if you can post an entire map to Firestore and if not, the most appropriate way to.

Answer (score 0):

As you say,
"Can someone let me know if you can post an entire map to Firestore and if not, the most appropriate way to."

So try this way to post data(example).

```
Map map=Map();
map ={"name":"abc","id":"1"};

Future<bool> createStudent(String schoolId) async {
 var newStudent = await db .collection('schoolStudents') .doc(schoolId)
 .collection('students')
 .add({
 'studentFirstName': _profile.studentFirstName,
 'studentSurname': _profile.studentSurname, 
'yearLevel': _profile.yearLevel, 
'preferredHand': _profile.preferredHand, 
'background': map,
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that object you would like to add as `background` filed in Firestore is nested. This is because the `background` field of the `Profile` object is already a map from the beginning, so adding brackets (`{}`) around it in `add` method is creating `Set` of `Map` objects, and Set is not among of [Types in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). This is the reason of the error.

So it seems that it's enough to remove brackets (`{}`) from `add` method:

```
Future<bool> createStudent(String schoolId) async {
  var newStudent = await db
    .collection('schoolStudents')
    .doc(schoolId)
    .collection('students')
    .add({
      'studentFirstName': _profile.studentFirstName,
      'studentSurname': _profile.studentSurname,
      'yearLevel': _profile.yearLevel,
      'preferredHand': _profile.preferredHand,
      'background': _profile.background,
})
```